# Gatsby useStaticQuery giving causing 'The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched'. Query works in graphiql and on hot reload, not page load

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

As the title says I have a static query for the publicURL of an svg to display. This works fine in graphiql and I have very similar queries in other files for other svgs, but for some reason this exact one is giving me errors. The strangest part of these errors is the icon will appear if I comment out the query, save the file and let gatsby hot reload, then uncomment it, save and hot reload again.

here is a branch reproducing the error: https://github.com/RyanCallahan312/Portfolio/tree/gatsby-bug

also the specific component in question.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

interface Icons {
    allFile: {
        nodes: [{ publicURL: string}];
    };
}

const ProjectCard: React.FC = () => {
    const icons: Icons = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
        allFile(
            filter: {relativeDirectory: {eq: "icons"}, name: {eq: "eye-white"}}
        ) {
            nodes {
                publicURL
            }
        }
    }
    `);

    return (
        <div>
            <a>
                <img
                    width='32px'
                    src={
                        icons.allFile.nodes[0].publicURL
                    }
                />
            </a>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ProjectCard;
```

stack trace:

```
Uncaught Error: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched.

This is likely a bug in Gatsby and if refreshing the page does not fix it, please open an issue in https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues
    at useStaticQuery (webpack-internal:///./.cache/gatsby-browser-entry.js:117)
    at ProjectCard (webpack-internal:///./src/components/projectCard/projectCard.tsx:19)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
```

I've tried running `gatsby clean` then deleting node modules and package-lock.json, then installing and running everything clean. I've also tried deleting my npm cache and the repo from my pc then cloning it again.

Thanks in advance for help on this, I've been stuck for about 2 days now.

Comment: Created an issue in gatsby's github repo: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/31085

Answer (score 2):

I'm not facing any issue running the project in Node `12.16.1`. The project builds without issues and I'm able to see the eye in the `/projects` path:

[image]

Assuming that the query is properly fetching the data. Try the following:

```
npm uninstall gatsby 
rm -rf node_modules
npm install gatsby 
rm package-lock.json 
npm install
gatsby develop
```

Until here, what you have tried so far apparently. Play with the Node version as well (what will require you to redo all the processes).

(Re)Sources:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24902
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/24890
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/26563

Comment: I was on node v12.19.0, but I tried switching to v12.16.1, re-cloning and trying your steps, but still no luck. By chance did you pull from the branch labeled gatsby-bug-workaround? 

That branch has a work around so the issue doesnt occur. Also with the issues I actually just opened one myself because it seems to be similar to three other issues from the last month that all have the same hot-reloading behavior.

Comment: I've checkout to `gatsby-bug` (pulled all changes from the repo) and also tried `gatsby-bug-workaround`. Both works